# offline message hook for group chats

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I've got an iOS app backed with ejabberd, with a small extension based on offline_message_hook that uses APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) to deliver push notifications of messages that are sent to offline users. This doesn't work out so well for group chats though, so I'm looking for a strategy that would do the same for offline users that are part of a group chat. Do MUCs even keep track of users that are part of the room but offline? Would I need to extend them in some way to keep track of this? Could I subtract the set of invited users from the set of online users to get the offline users? What hook should I be using to do this?

Any suggestions on this or advice on a better strategy are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The XMPP specification for Multi User Chat define MUC rooms as presence based. Per definition, a user is only in a chat room when it is connected. When he gets offline, users gets out of the chatroom. It means he does not receive message at all. This explains why they are not stored offline.

This is for now a feature of XEP-0045. Some future XMPP specifications (aka MUC 2) may address this issue in the future. Currently, MUC + offline storage of message is not possible in XMPP.

Comment: Thanks. when are you planning to release MUC 2 ? can you give me some guidelance to how to do it in MUC 1.

Comment: It is not possible in the way it is defined on MUC specification. You have to invent your own protocol / extension to match your requirements. You could for example use new hooks added in ejabberd MUC module (muc_filter_packet). Regarding MUC2, XSF have not yet written the specifications of MUC 2 so it is months away.